# How to get child rows in DB2 for a specific subset of parent rows?

Tags: sql, db2, hierarchical-data

I have a parent row and child rows on 7-10 separate tables, with a unique key tying the rows on the child tables to the parent row.  For a search feature,  I need to retrieve the parent and all the matching child rows, based on a query against the data in the parent table.  There are up to 5000 matching parent rows.  Currently we are re-running the query against each of the child tables, like:

```
select data from child 
where key in (select key from parent where search_criteria)
```

This seems pretty inelegant especially as we continue to add more child tables.  Is there a better way to do this in DB2?

Some of my thoughts:

- Will DB2 reuse the results of that select?  What about if there is a high volume of queries?
- I know the keys after the parent query, so I could pass them in the SQL, but that SQL would get crazy with 5000 keys, and presumably exceed the SQL limit.
- Would it be worth it to store the keys as a temp table, or would the setup / teardown be excessive?

Comment: What is consuming this data? Is it a front-end or some sort of back-end processing system?

Comment: It is a front-end, and the end-users are generating the queries (indirectly, not by providing SQL).

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't getting results from all the child tables in one go?  Getting it a file at a time (native I/O and especially with SQL) is generally not the best way - although sometimes it's the only way.  I don't think that DB2 will cache the results of the inner select - and you're likely to get better performance off an explicit join, if I remember right.  Storing the keys in a `GLOBAL TEMPORARY` table would work okay (insert data when creating the table, don't load from your program), if you still need to query the child tables individually.

Comment: @X-Zero: How do you mean?  There are multiple child rows in some of the tables, so I can't just flatten the data into a SELECT with 100 or so columns.

Comment: What's wrong with getting a result set that has multiple child rows?  The exact nature and returns of your result set are completely dependant on your needs, but multiple 'child' rows are probably the norm in SQL database access.  For one thing, it's (usually) more efficient to get multiple rows, than to query multiple times for single rows.  If you're on an iSeries, you may be thinking too much along the lines of how native RPG I/O has to be used - SQL wasn't really intended to be used that way.  SQL results are often going to look like an un-normalized table, or Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an ideal scenario to use a RPG program and use a stored procedure that calls/consumes it. This way, you're not making so many round trips. Pass your search criteria to the stored procedure and the stored proc invokes the RPG program. Let RPG chain the 'files' together, which would speed up your query.